# How to use fragment in Ajax.RouteLink?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, routelink

I have a working Ajax.RouteLink, I want to add a fragment.  I can't figure out correct syntax.

Working route without fragment:

```
return Ajax.RouteLink(
            linkText,
            routeName,
            new { caseNo = caseNo, controller = controllerName, option = contentOption },
            new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "caseContent", HttpMethod = "Post", OnBegin = onBegin, OnSuccess = onSuccess },
            new { Class = cssClass + (contentOption != null && contentOption == contentView ? " active" : "") });
```

Compiler Error RouteLink with fragment:

```
return Ajax.RouteLink(
            linkText: linkText,
            routeName: routeName,
            protocol: null,
            hostName: null,
            fragment: fragment,
            routeValues: new { caseNo = caseNo, controller = controllerName, option = contentOption },
            ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "caseContent", HttpMethod = "Post", OnBegin = onBegin, OnSuccess = onSuccess },
            htmlAttributes: new { Class = cssClass + (contentOption != null && contentOption == contentView ? " active" : "") }
            );
```

Errors with routeValues and htmlAttributes.  Cannot convert from anonymous type.

I tried:

```
routeValues: new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary() { caseNo = caseNo, controller = controllerName, option = contentOption }
```

but then the complier complains about my routing parms (caseNo, controller, option).

Also, is it okay to leave protocol and hostname null, as I'm not changing those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>The only problem I see is your use of `Class` in htmlAttributes for both calls of `Ajax.RouteLink` you posted. You can't use `Class`, as it's a reserved word. The workaround is to prefix an `@`, i.e. `@class`.</del>

Sorry, you're right about that. I got tricked, I think, by the syntax highlighting. Anyways, after taking another look, I found your problem. I don't use any of the `Ajax.*` helpers personally, so I'm not familiar with their signatures. So I took a look at [the MSDN documentation on the extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.routelink(v=vs.118).aspx). Simply there's no overload that allows passing a `fragment` *and* anonymous objects for `routeValues` and `htmlAttributes`. If you want to use the `fragment` version(s) then you must pass `RouteValueDictionary` and `IDictionary<string, object>` for `routeValues` and `htmlAttributes`, respectively.

The issue you're having with `RouteValueDictionary` is that you need to actually initialize with dictionary members, so `{ "caseNo", caseNo }` rather than `caseNo = caseNo`.

Comment: I believe class is reserved but not Class.  Regardless that's not my current error, as the first call works.

Comment: Ah....I reworked RouteValueDictionary as described and its compiles.  :)  Thanks.

Comment: routeValues: new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary { { "caseNo", caseNo }, { "controller", controllerName }, { "option", contentOption } },